# Show Images based on two checkboxes state

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to achieve following using HTML, CSS, JS.

I have two check boxes and 4 Images:

- If none of them are checked -> show Image1 - Hide others
- If 1st is checked  -> show Image2 - Hide others
- If 2nd is checked -> show Image3 - Hide others
- If both are checked -> show Image4 - Hide others

```
 <input id="chk-box1" type="checkbox"> checkbox 1 </input>
 <input id="chk-box2" type="checkbox" > checkbox 2 </input>
 <img alt="" id="1" src="1.jpg" />
 <img alt="" id="2" src="2.jpg" />
 <img alt="" id="3" src="3.jpg" />
 <img alt="" id="4" src="4.jpg" />
```

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried.

Comment: What have you tried? Stackoverflow is not for outsourcing your programming. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use some jquery to handle showing the images

```
if ($("#chk-box1").is(":checked"))
{
    if ($("#chk-box2").is(":checked"))
    {
        $("#1").hide()
        $("#2").hide()
        $("#3").hide()
        $("#4").show()
    }
    else
    {
        $("#1").hide()
        $("#2").show()
        $("#3").hide()
        $("#4").hide()
    }
}
else
{
    if ($("#chk-box2").is(":checked"))
    {
        $("#1").hide()
        $("#2").hide()
        $("#3").show()
        $("#4").hide()
    }
    else 
    {
        $("#1").show()
        $("#2").hide()
        $("#3").hide()
        $("#4").hide()
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a jQuery tag on the question.

Answer (score 1):

This should help : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecbuilder/rq6L1zq6/1/)**

**js**

```
var shown = 1;

function toggleImages() {
    if (document.getElementById('chk-box1').checked) {
        if (document.getElementById('chk-box2').checked) {
            showImage(4);
        } else {
            showImage(2);
        }
    } else if (document.getElementById('chk-box2').checked) {
        showImage(3);
    } else {
        showImage(1);
    }
}

function showImage(n) {
    document.getElementById(shown).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(n).style.display = 'block';
    shown = n;

}
```

**html**

```
<input id="chk-box1" type="checkbox" onchange="toggleImages();">checkbox 1</input>
<input id="chk-box2" type="checkbox" onchange="toggleImages();">checkbox 2</input>
<br/>
<img alt="1" id="1" src="1.jpg" title="1"/>
<img alt="2" id="2" src="2.jpg" title="2" style="display:none;" />
<img alt="3" id="3" src="3.jpg" title="3" style="display:none;" />
<img alt="4" id="4" src="4.jpg" title="4" style="display:none;" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers insofar are hardcoded to use the id of the elements.

I have built a different approach where one uses `js-` classes to bind the javascript to, and data-attributes to define which image should be shown when. This makes the code much less hardcoded and can be expanded both if multiple checkboxes should be added and if the way the images should be displayed should change.

```js
(function($, document) {
"use strict";

var $document = $(document);

var CheckboxHandler = {
  $checkboxes: null,
  $images: null,
  bind: function() {
    var self = this;

    this.$checkboxes.each(function() {
      var $checkbox = $(this);
      $checkbox.on('change', function() {
        self.triggerImageToShow();
      });
    });
  },
  triggerImageToShow: function() {
    var showImageFor = [];

    this.$checkboxes.each(function() {
      var $checkbox = $(this);
      if ($checkbox.is(':checked')) {
        showImageFor.push(parseInt($checkbox.attr('data-checkbox')));
      }
    });

    this.$images.each(function() {
      var $image = $(this);
      $image.trigger('show-image-for-checkboxes', [showImageFor]);
    })
  },
  init: function($checkboxes, $images) {
    this.$checkboxes = $checkboxes;
    this.$images = $images;
    this.bind();
  }
};

var Image = {
  showForCheckboxes: [],
  bind: function() {
    var self = this;

    this.$image.on('show-image-for-checkboxes', function(event, showForCheckboxes) {
      var isArrayEqual = JSON.stringify(showForCheckboxes) == JSON.stringify(self.showForCheckboxes)

      if (isArrayEqual) {
        self.$image.show();
      } else {
        self.$image.hide();
      }
    });
  },
  init: function($image) {
    this.$image = $image;
    this.showForCheckboxes = $image.data('show-for-checkboxes');
    this.bind();
  }
};

$document.ready(function() {
  var $images = $('.js-toggle-image');
  var $checkboxes = $('.js-toggler');

  var checkboxHandler = Object.create(CheckboxHandler);
  checkboxHandler.init($checkboxes, $images);

  var startToShowImageFor = [];

  $images.each(function() {
    var image = Object.create(Image);
    image.init($(this));
    image.$image.trigger('show-image-for-checkboxes', [startToShowImageFor]);
  });
});
}(jQuery, document));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>
    <input class="js-toggler" data-checkbox="1" type="checkbox" />checkbox 1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input class="js-toggler" data-checkbox="2" type="checkbox" />checkbox 2
  </label>
</div>
<div>

  <img alt="" class="js-toggle-image" data-show-for-checkboxes="[]" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=First+image" />
  <img alt="" class="js-toggle-image" data-show-for-checkboxes="[1]" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=Second+image" />
  <img alt="" class="js-toggle-image" data-show-for-checkboxes="[2]" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=Third+image" />
  <img alt="" class="js-toggle-image" data-show-for-checkboxes="[1,2]" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=Fourth+image" />
</div>
```